# Java- Convert treeSet to List

Tags: java

how can I convert this to a List of the same object type?

```
TreeSet<FieldBean> Fields = new TreeSet<FieldBean>();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[One of the constructors of `ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) takes a collection as an argument and fills the list with the items contained in that collection:

```
List<FieldBean> list = new ArrayList<FieldBean> (fields);
```